# Does Service Control Manager support verbose logging?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, services, event-viewer

I'm seeing persisistent errors logged in the System log time a nightly backup process runs:

*Event 7005, Service Control Manager.  The LoadUserProfile call failed
with the following error:  The system cannot find the file specified.*

I know what directory the backup process is backup up and it's clear from the error that some sort of file cannot be found, but the Windows Event Viewer doesn't seem to show exactly *what* file is missing.

Is there any way to switch it to verbose mode or to obtain a more detailed log that tells what file Windows cannot find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general answer, you can use [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to log all file and registry accesses; just tell it to exclude `SUCCESS` events.

[image]